# Dev/Test version of Google App Engine LogService

Tags: java, google-app-engine, service, jar, classpath

I'm trying to use a "test" or "dev" version of Google App Engine's [`LogService`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/log/LogService) so that I can use it in unit tests outside of GAE.

I included the `appengine-testing.jar`, `appengine-api.jar` and `appengine-api-stubs.jar` on my classpath, and see a class that looks like what I want:

> com.google.appengine.api.log.dev.LocalLogService

When I create an instance of this and try to look for a `fetch(LogQuery)` method, I don't see any. So clearly this isn't the class I'm looking for. Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Specifically, I'm looking for a GAE class that acts as a test version of `LogService` the same way that the other services have test versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use something like [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) to mock the GAE `LoggingService`:

```
@Test
public void myUnitTest() {
    // Given
    MyPojo fixture = new MyPojo();

    LoggingService mockService = Mockito.mock(Logging.Service);

    Mockito.doNothing().when(mockService).fetchLogs(Mockito.any());

    fixture.setLoggingService(mockService);

    // When
    fixture.logSomethingToGAELogs("Some string to log");

    // Then - verify
    Mockito.verify(mockService).fetchLogs("Some string to log");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe [com.google.appengine.api.log.dev.LocalLogService](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.6.1/appengine-java-sdk-1.6.1.zip!/appengine-java-sdk-1.6.1/docs/testing/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/log/dev/LocalLogService.html) is the one you are looking for, the reason why it has a different class signature than [com.google.appengine.api.log.LogService](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/log/LogService) is LocalLogService is just a expectant or half-baked implementation. It is possible that this class will be changed in the future release.

If you look into [LogService source](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/log/LogServiceImpl.java?r=229), the fetch method returns log records formed as an Iterable<RequestLogs>. In the LocalLogService, instead of fetching the log records from live app server, it simply read logs records (formed as LogReadResponse which is generally a wrapper of Iterable<RequestLogs>) from memory. The following sample code demonstrate how it works:

```
public void foo() {
  String requestId = "1234";

  localLogService = new LocalLogService();

  // Mock a request log record:
  localLogService.addRequestInfo("sample-app", "1", requestId, null, null, startTimeUsec, endTimeUsec, 
          "GET", "", "HTTP/1.1", null, true, 200, null);

  // Mock an app log record:
  localLogService.addAppLogLine(requestId, startTimeUsec, 2, "this is a sample log message.");   

  LogReadRequest request = new LogReadRequest();
  // Filter request 1234:
  request.addRequestId(requestId);
  // Version id must match the one you just mocked, do not use dot in-between:
  request.addVersionId("1");
  request.setIncludeIncomplete(true);
  request.setIncludeAppLogs(true);

  Status status = new Status();
  status.setSuccessful(true);

  // Read mocked log records from memory:
  LogReadResponse response = localLogService.read(status, request);

  for (RequestLog log : response.logs()) {
    System.out.println("request log: " + log.getCombined());
    for (LogLine line : log.lines()) {
      System.out.println("app log: " + line.getLogMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Sample output:

> request log: - - - [8/Feb/2013:09:51:13 -0800] "GET  HTTP/1.1" 200 - - -
>   app log: this is a sample log message.

For a better code design, you could wrap LocalLogService into an implementation of LogService to make the class signature more consistent.